# Techniques of estimating integrals, asymptotic behavior of Li(x)

Tags: integration, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I need help understanding the logic and build an rigorous intuition proving that if $x \gt 2$, then:

$$\int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{t \log^{3} t} \lt \frac{1}{2 \log^{2}2}$$

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: What does $\log^3t$ means? $\log(\log(\log t))$ or $(\log t)^3$?

Comment: My approach is as follows: $\int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{t (\log t)^3 = \frac{-1}{2 (\log x)^2}+ \frac{1}{2 (\log 2)^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
$$\int_2^x \frac{dt}{t\ln^3(t)}<\int_2^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t\ln^3(t)}=\frac{1}{2\ln^2(2)}$$
and we are done.

Comment: I like that answer as the shortcut! Brilliant! Can we discuss the asymptotic behavior also if we didn’t use the above logic?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{t \log^{3} t} = \frac12\left(\frac{1}{\log^{2}2}-\frac{1}{\log^{2}x}\right)<\frac{1}{2\log^{2}2}$$
How much logic would one need for that? How much logic can one muster while seriously combining "rigorous" and "intuition"?